# What is the receiver of instance methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

What is the receiver of Ruby instance methods? By receiver I mean:

```
def obj.talk  --> obj is receiver, talk is the message (method)

end
```

Based on what I've read, it seems that it may be `self`, but how can this be considering the fact that if you actually write within the class Animal, `self.m`, it will turn itself into a class method that can only be called by the class.

i.e.:

```
class Animal        
  def m   --> instance method 
    puts "hi"
  end

  def self.m --> if receiver is self, self makes this a class method
  end
end
```

My question is: what would the receiver of the instance method be, specifically the part in which the method is defined, if you were to fully write it out (I'm assuming that the instance method has a receiver) ?

`Class Animal;def some.object;end` --> What is the value of the object `some` if written out in an .rb file.

Comment: why is it not the instance object? (i.e. `a = Animal.new`, `a` can respond to `m`; that makes it the receiver of `m`.)

Comment: There is not a single message send in your code, therefore there are no receivers anywhere.